# Automatically update list items that get their information from a different library

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, library

I'm trying to see what my options are to accomplish the following:

I have a list and a library on a site.  The list will provide a link to the document in the attached library, as well as display associated column data from the library (the library document properties, of course).

When a document is moved (created) to the library, a workflow creates an item in the list, and populates the columns there with the data from the columns in the library doc properties.

How am I able to refresh the list items when the library doc properties are modified? Can a workflow accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a workflow on the library which should trigger on item creation and **create item**  action and in the configuration of **create item**  select the custom list and map all document library columns (document properties) with the **custom list** column (the custom list should have the needed mapping columns). That's it - on item creation on document library your custom list will be updated and refreshed.

For details steps, you may refer to the below article :

[How to a copy list item to another list using SharePoint designer workflow](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/how-to-a-copy-list-item-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Comment: I hadn't seen that there was an UPDATE option in workflows.  Thank you.